# Memory barriers and the singleton pattern

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, singleton, memory-barriers

I am having a hard time understanding memory barriers and why barriers are needed in the following code? (Taken from the wikipedia about double checked locking)

```
std::atomic<Singleton*> Singleton::m_instance;
std::mutex Singleton::m_mutex;

Singleton* Singleton::getInstance() {
    Singleton* tmp = m_instance.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire); // <- 1
    if (tmp == nullptr) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        tmp = m_instance.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        if (tmp == nullptr) {
            tmp = new Singleton;
            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release); // <- 2
            m_instance.store(tmp, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Why does fence 2 exist?  Doesn't the lock make sure that access to the `m_instance` is atomic and will not be affected by code reordering?

Also could someone please give me an example of a race condition that would be present if the barriers were removed and the `m_instance` variable were not an `std::atomic`?

Comment: As I understand, `m_instance.store()` doesn't prevent the CPU from reordering the body of `Singleton` constructor until after `tmp` is published (thanks to relaxed order). Absent the fence, other threads may observe non-null pointer, pointing to the object that's still under construction.

Comment: As to the race condition: just merely reading a non-atomic variable in order to compare it to `nullptr`, while another thread is assigning to it, is already a data race that exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik does that imply that the only undefined behavior is that which is related to ordering of instructions?

Comment: *"does that imply that the only undefined behavior is that which is related to ordering of instructions?"* I do not understand this question.

Comment: First, two threads reading a variable is not a problem - it's one reading while another is writing, or both writing, that constitute a data race. Second, I said "non-atomic variable": in the above program, the variable being read and written simultaneously, `m_instance`,  is in fact atomic. If you make it non-atomic, then the program would no longer be correct. I must admit I don't at all follow your chain of reasoning.

Comment: I also have a hard time with this sentence "Therefore the above program implies that the only undefined behavior they considered was that threads reading the same variable at the same time without a barrier (which prevents out of order ordering of instructions) is undefined behavior." I think they considered all undefined behaviors when they wrote it, what scenario are you considering that you think could be UB but you are concluding from the example is not UB?

Comment: it appears that i misread the comment. i thought the comment was saying that reading two variables at the same time from two threads was undefined. sorry about that!